# c# FileSystemWatcher on HFS+ file system

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

Is anyone aware of issues using FileSystemWatcher to watch a directory with file system HFS+ (Apple)?  The following code works fine for a local windows directory, but is never triggered for a network HFS+ directory.

```
var fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher
{
    Path = Configs.DirWatchedFiles,
    Filter = "*.*",
    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
};
fileWatcher.Changed += FileChanged;
fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: I think the filesystemwatcher doesn't work on remote directories very well. Having this problem on a NAS formatted using FAT or NTFS ( I'm not sure about the actual filesystem ). I once decided to poll rather than to rely on the watcher.

Answer (score 1):

Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

The only platforms supported are Windows 7, Windows Vista SP1 or later, Windows XP SP3, Windows XP SP2 x64 Edition, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core supported with SP1 or later), Windows Server 2003 SP2

Comment: I think the platforms section do not refer to the use of the class but the platforms the .NET framework can be installed to.

Comment: Right and Im pretty sure this requires .net framework support on the file system you are monitoring.

Comment: thank you, Sascha and samack, for your replies.  this confirms my suspicion that I'll have to find an alternative approach to monitor these files.